# 2 cells, same value, same format, match function doesn't work

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to compare two columns, but the problem is that `match` returns #N/A values even if it's obvious that there are same values in two columns. I've isolated two values that are exactly the same for testing purposes. I know that sometimes Excel doesn't recognize same value if they are different formats, but this is not the case (F0).

[image]

So, when I enter confirm value in B2, everything will work as it should, but I am not able to do that for couple thousand values.

Link to [Example WB](http://www.filedropper.com/examplestack)

Thanks for help.

Comment: to solve the question if there is a leading space or not, do a LEN on both cells and see if this produces the same number as well

Comment: Length of both values is exactly tha same, 8 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your sample file, I got an error flag on cell **B2** stating that it was a number stored as text`*`.  This is not the same as being formatted as text, so the formats are indeed the same, but the values stored are different.  If you convert all the text numbers to true numbers first, the error should go away.

A fast way to fix this is

1. Highlight the entire column with potential numbers-as-text values.
2. On the **Data** tab, select **Text to Columns**
3. Leave step 1 set to **Delimited**.
4. Clear all checkboxes on step 2.
5. Make sure that the Column data format is set to **General**.
6. Click finish.

This will reset all your values to a general formatting, after which you can apply the number format of your choice.

---

`*` I have no idea how you got the data into this undetectable text state.  I was able to replicate the number-as-text error, and the matched formatting values, but never at the same time.  Must be something weird about how the data was imported or converted.

Comment: Data was imported from some financial website. I gave one example in provided workbook, but majority of values in that column has leading zeros, so that must be the reason for that strange formatting. Anyway, thanks for your help.